# An array of maximum values from a list of 2D numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

a = np.random.rand(4,2,2)

array([[[ 0.10723991,  0.20947733],
        [ 0.02998244,  0.64829337]],

```
   [[ 0.1707575 ,  0.34311093],
    [ 0.7368306 ,  0.83202149]],

   [[ 0.10195594,  0.81748548],
    [ 0.51577596,  0.84025512]],

   [[ 0.64234408,  0.82321103],
    [ 0.78017441,  0.29398195]]])
```

How to get an array of maximum values for each element as:

array([ 0.64234408,  0.82321103],
      [ 0.78017441,  0.84025512])

Answer (score 2):

You can use the numpy `max` function to find the maximum element over a specific axis (or axes).

For the example you gave `np.max(a, axis=0)` is what you are looking for.

Equivalently, you can use the `max` method of your array object: `a.max(axis=0)`.